# How do I change the contents of a block when I click on a button?

Tags: jquery, css

I don't know if I'm making myself clear, but as best I can.
How do I change the content of the same div where the button is located when I click on the button? 
There is a div with 4 buttons
[image]

When you click on them appears different content in the same div and the buttons disappear.
[image]

you can see example  on the website https://mad.ac/ 
My menu structure

```html
            <div class="notes__pane notes__pane--summary">
              <h3 class="notes__heading text-h3">Notes</h3>
              <ul class="notes__container list-reset">
                <li>
                  <button class="note__button">
                    <article class="note">
                      <h3>
                        <span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        Text
                      </h3>
                      <p>Text</p>
                    </article>
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button class="note__button">
                    <article class="note">
                      <h3>
                        <span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true">✅</span>
                        Text
                      </h3>
                      <p>Text</p>
                    </article>
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button class="note__button">
                    <article class="note">
                      <h3>
                        <span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                       Text
                      </h3>
                      <p>Text</p>
                    </article>
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @charlietfl I understand, but I don't have the code, but I would like to know the solution

Comment: Start by providing a basic sample showing the html structure and more detailed explanation of what exactly you are trying to accomplish along with source for the new data

Comment: At simplest terms it can be done by hiding the first navigation div and showing the associated content element when clicked. Then do the opposite when back arrow clicked